# IoC framework in published NuGet library?

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control

I'm going to be making a .NET library meant to be exposed via NuGet, and I'm not sure what sort of IoC framework I should be using, if any at all.

Normally I just use Unity, but I have a couple concerns:

1. The framework conflicts with a different version of the framework the user is trying to use.
2. The framework would weigh down the user's app, I'm assuming it would be annoying to pull in an IoC dll just for using my library.

What is the common practice here? Embed a lightweight IoC? Go without it? I'd like to be able to use an IoC framework to support DI and keep my library unit testable.

Comment: You should make your library [DI Friendly](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/).

Comment: I've had a lot of experience and success using Autofac with nuget packages.  Please take a look at the Autofac.Module http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/modules.html type.  Then in your application composition root you can bootstrap each nuget package either by scanning assemblies (slow) or explicitly registering them with your Autofac ContainerBuilder instance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your best bet could be providing some extension points to let your library consumers decide how they want to instantiate your underlying components using whichever IoC container of their choice.

For example:

```
// It's a bit of pseudo-code
LibraryConfiguration config = new LibraryConfiguration();

config.Container.Configure(containerConfig =>
{
    WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

    containerConfig.DefaultLifeStyle.Transient();
    containerConfig.LifeStyleFor<ISomeLibraryInterface>().Singleton();

    containerConfig.RegisterUsing((dependencyType, dependencyImpl) => container.Register(dependencyType, dependencyImpl));

    containerConfig.ResolveComponentUsing((dependencyType, args) => container.Resolve(dependencyType, args));
    containerConfig.ReleaseComponentUsing((dependencyInstance) => container.Release(dependencyInstance));
);

// Internally, your library will consume the whole configuration to blindly
// work with the container of choice!  
LibraryRoot libraryRoot = LibraryRoot.Create(config);
```

Note that it's an hypothetical code, probably you should need to extend and/or specialize it more.

Once you've already implemented a configuration API like the proposed one, you could provide configuration templates to popular IoC/DI containers in order to let third-party developers work on their own configuration on top of some defaults, which can smooth the overall usage of your library.

#### OP said in some comment

> Requiring the user to plug in their IoC like this is way more work than I want to require of them. I want to make it as streamlined as possible to use the library

Right, if you double check my answer, you'll find the part on which I suggest you that you should provide configuration templates.

Morover, you can go further and provide `LibraryConfiguration.Container` extension methods to auto-configure a concrete IoC container with no effort:

```
public static class WindsorContainerConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static void UseWindsor(this LibraryContainerConfiguration containerConfig)
    {
        WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
        containerConfig.DefaultLifeStyle.Transient();
        containerConfig.LifeStyleFor<ISomeLibraryInterface>().Singleton();

        containerConfig.RegisterUsing((dependencyType, dependencyImpl) => container.Register(dependencyType, dependencyImpl));
        containerConfig.ResolveComponentUsing((dependencyType, args) => container.Resolve(dependencyType, args));
        containerConfig.ReleaseComponentUsing((dependencyInstance) => container.Release(dependencyInstance));
    }
}
```

So your library consumers will be able to configure it to use Windsor, Ninject, StructureMap or any other popular IoC container with a one-liner solution:

```
LibraryConfiguration config = new LibraryConfiguration();
config.Container.UseWindsor();
```

Comment: "You define an interface to generalize underlying IoC/DI operations and a possible implementation should be wired up to a configuration object". You are advising the [Conforming Container anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/conforming-container/).

Comment: @Steven My intention wasn't defining a full IoC interface, but just something like `Resolve` that could be used by `ObjectFactory.Create(config)` to start the DI from the top-most object (i.e. `LibraryObject`). I believe that this doesn't fall on that anti-pattern, does it?

Comment: @Steven I understand that a minimum cosmetic change like passing a `LibraryObject` factory as a delegate (i.e. `Func<LibraryObject>`) would avoid an abuse of the *dependency resolver approach*...

Comment: You are correct Matias, a Conforming Container is a registration API. As long as it only contains a Resolve API the most it can be is a Service Locator; much less painful.

Comment: @Steven Well, I'm rephrasing my answer to throw away the dependency resolver concept by providing a more functional and restrictive approach.

Comment: @Steven Done! I beileve that this way we've absolutely closed all *bad doors*. No chance to fall into the service locator nor conforming container anti-patterns. Am I right?

Comment: @Steven Now I understand that it's up to the OP to extend my idea, because clearly the whole configuration API should provide extension points to support the most feature-rich IoC container possible (for example, it would be nice to support *scopes*... but not all containers support them).

Comment: Requiring the user to plug in their IoC like this is way more work than I want to require of them. I want to make it as streamlined as possible to use the library.

Comment: @RandomEngy You forgot to read the part where I explain you that you can provide configuration templates, almost like OWIN hosting does. You can manually configure it, or you can provide extension methods like `configuration.UseWindsor()`, `configuration.UseNinject()` so you provide an easy path to your developers!

Comment: @RandomEngy See my updated answer where I elaborate this idea with a code sample...

Comment: Hmm. You'd need to suppress pulling in dlls from all the myriad of IoC frameworks you're including helper methods for. And you'd need to make your IoC cater to the lowest common denominator of any IoC out there (existing or future), and would be expected to maintain it for any new IoC frameworks that came out, and for breaking changes of existing ones. At this point it seems less hassle to just embed a simple one, require no setup on the users part and be free of the maintenance headache.

Comment: @RandomEngy The worst point of your proposed approach is your library won't have the chance to be integrated into an actual IoC container. Most modern developers love that they could use their already choosen IoC container and integrate libraries into the same container rather than having to deal with a different, undocumented, untested and/or weak IoC implementation...

Comment: @RandomEngy Such *default IoC* could be some like Ninject, which is a very light-weight one that should work for most scenarios. It can be a direct dependency of your own project and your NuGet package can define such dependency so Ninject will be automatically installed into the target project.

Comment: @RandomEngy In the other hand, you're wrong when you say that some IoC container will be catered to the lowest common demoninator. My first proposal had this issue, but once Seteven and me exchanged some messages, I realized that a functional-style configuration API can be the easiest and more flexible one. Since you work with closures, you can customize the whole configuration to support specific features of each IoC container! :)

Comment: @RandomEngy About the thing of having to maintain the compatibility with many IoC containers... Usually IoC containers don't change much in years... BTW, do you have that library already published on GitHub or some other site? I would love to check it out so I can think if you really need an IoC container at all...

Comment: The surface area isn't very large so I was just going to expose the entry points as interfaces on static properties, to let consumers register them as they see fit. We don't have the library published yet, but it's complex enough to have dependencies between components. We *may* be able to get away with manual injection here but I was still curious about how others handled this. Also don't quite see how this would allow you to do things supply names with registrations, since the user's injected IoC framework might not support that.

Comment: @RandomEngy I see.. Some suggestion: don't do that thing of exposing entry points as static properties. I understand those *entry points* are part of some configuration/initialization object, aren't they? I would use manual constructor injection and I would turn that static class into an instance one. This way others will be able to integrate your own library as a DI component.

Comment: @RandomEngy About giving you a definitive approach to solve your scenario, I would say that I prefer to see your source code once you've already published the library...You can comment out again here and I'll be glad to check the code to see what I would do in your case...